# Collect RxJS Observable to Array

Tags: reactive-extensions-js, rxjs

I'd like to use RxJS to "bridge" async world of events with sync world.
Specifically I want to create an function which returns an array of events collected during some time interval.

I can create Observable which does what I want

```js
    var source = Rx.Observable
    .interval(100 /* ms */)
    .bufferWithTime(1000).take(1)
```

I can print correct values just fine

```js
    var subscription = source.subscribe(
        function (x) {
            console.log('Next: ' + JSON.stringify(x));
        },
        function () {
            console.log('Completed');   
        });
```

This prints

```
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
    Completed
```

But want I want is to assign this array to variable. Conceptually I want something like

`var collectedDuringSecond = source.toPromise.getValue()`

The idea is that getValue would block so after the line above is done collectedDuringSecond will contain [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: first, blocking in JavaScript is not the best idea. Rx specifically allows you to avoid a lot of the pain introduced by asynchronous programming, so why do you want to block to get the value?

Comment: I am  new to JavaScript, so you might be right I don't want blocking ;). Basically, this particular data set is fairly static even it uses events as a delivery mechanism. Thus I wanted to expose a "simpler" synchronous API to API client. Based on your comment I should probably reconsider and just return Observable and let client consume events any way they want

Comment: That's definitely a better approach. *If* for some reason (I don't know why) you wanted to hide Rx, you could provide your API with a node-style callback (`function (err, value) { ... }`) instead of exposing the Observable. However, I would suggest exposing the Observable as part of the public API, since they can always just `subscribe` to that object, rather than providing the callback at the API call itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Synchronous event programming in JavaScript is highly restrictive. In fact, it may be impossible in a lot of cases. I tried hacking around with Rx to see if I could provide a synchronous interface without modifying the Rx source, and (for good reason) it's not possible with straight JavaScript.

I would suggest exposing the Observable as part of your API, and allowing consumers to handle it from there (with a nudge to use Rx, of course ;).

```
function MyClass () {

    this.getArrayOfStuffAsObservable = function () {
        return Rx.Observable.interval(100)
            .bufferWithTime(1000).take(1);
    };

    // this is optional and I don't recommend it, since you already have Rx available.
    // additionally, consumers will probably miss the fact that you can dispose
    // of the subscription.
    this.getArrayOfStuff = function (callback) {
        var value;
        return this.getArrayOfStuffAsObservable()
            .subscribe(
                function (x) {
                    value = x;
                },
                function (err) {
                    callback(err);
                },
                function () {
                    if (hasValue) {
                        callback(undefined, value);
                    } else {
                        callback('did not receive value');
                    }
                });

    };
};
```

As an additional note, you may want to use `toArray` in conjunction with `take` instead of `bufferWithTime` for this *specific* example (it's really two ways of doing the same thing, but one is based on time and the other based on item count). `toArray` creates an Observable which will collect all of the values of the underlying observable, and yield those values as an array when the underlying Observable completes.

```
this.getArrayOfStuffAsObservable = function () {
    return Rx.Observable.interval(100)
        .take(10)
        .toArray();
};
```