# How can I return the Http response?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs

I'm wondering if following thing is possible to do:

I need to return the response from http `GET` request directly instead of returning `Observable<Response>` instance.

The example might clarify whole thing a bit:

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  constructor( @Inject(Http) protected http: Http) { }
  static model: { [uri: string]: any } = {}
  public get(uri: string): any {
    if (typeof ExampleService.model[uri] === 'undefined') {
      ExampleService.model[uri] = this.http.get(uri).map(response => response.json()) // additionally do some magic here, it is Observable<any> instance now
    }
    return ExampleService.model[uri]
  }
}
```

---

Summary: according to [Günter Zöchbauer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38220058/1732775) above solution is not possible, instead of that I need to use something like this:

```
  public get(uri: string): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      if (!ExampleService.model[uri]) {
        let sub = this.http.get(uri).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(
          src => observer.next(ExampleService.model[uri] = src),
          err => console.error(err),
          () => observer.complete()
        )
        return () => sub.unsubscribe()
      }
      observer.next(ExampleService.model[uri])
      observer.complete()
    })
  }
```

Comment: This link should help understand the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231909/collect-rxjs-observable-to-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible because the HTTP request is async and the `get()` method returns before the call to the server is even made. Instead when the response from the server arrives the callback passed to `subscribe(...)` is called.

There is no way to go back from async to sync execution.

You can only return the observable for the caller to subscribe to it and do something when the response arrives.